# moving web api controllers within solution

Tags: c#, api, location, asp.net-mvc-5, controllers

I have a Visual Studio MVC5 project, I also have a Telerik Data Access project, I have created Web Api controllers form my Data Access models. My question is:

Can I move the created controller files (.cs) from the root of my project to a folder? Like the Controllers folder for example.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the controllers to any folder and the web api framework will find it as long as your controllers implement the interface `System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController` or inherit from `ApiController`, which implements this interface and is a common usage pattern.